# Ruby, how to correctly decode mails with MIME multipart?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, imap, mime

I'm trying to write a system which could pull mails from gmail and get the content in Ruby. (using imap or pop) 
And as far as I know, there are '[ruby-gmail](https://github.com/dcparker/ruby-gmail)', 'mail' (the newer version of tmail) and 'action mailer' that might help me to do this.

I'm now trying 'mail' and 'ruby-gmail', and I use the decoded function like this:

```
gmail.inbox.emails[0].body.decoded
```

But some mails could be correctly decoded, but some couldn't.
The output of the decoded mail looks like this:

```
This is MIME multipart 6.
--__=_Part_Boundary_002_310696381.907173471
Content-Type: text/plain;
    charset="big5"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable

=AE=BC=A5=BF=A7A=A6n,
.......(some encoded content)
```

And to some other mails, the Content-Transfer-Encoding are base64. 
Is there any better way to correctly decode the mails? 
Or I just need to read into the mail, get the encoded part, 
and use Base64.decode64 or unpack.("M") to decode the mail?

Answer (score 10):

I don't know about 'gmail' gem, but 'mail' one works pretty well. Something like

```
require 'mail'
mail = Mail.new(mail_text)
mail.parts[0].body.decoded
```

should work (use 'n' instead of 0 for other parts)

Also be aware that it could be an attachment, so you'd need `mail.attachments[0].decoded`

Comment: Thanks for your help! I found why the output looks strange! It's because the original mail is in Chinese instead of English. What I need is the ascii and unicode decoder, but not the MIME decoder. Thanks for your help!

Comment: dont try `mail.body.decode` on a multipart message 'cos it doesn't work. test it before with multipart?